# Rails - How should one organize their model code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm sorry if this seems over simplified but I'm wondering quite specifically what the general consensus is on how model code should be organized.

Association declarations, if you think certain association types should be declared before others, accepts_nested_resource declarations, validations, custom validations, protected and private methods, module inclusions, everything and anything.

I've heard of weird gothcas that can occur with the ordering of different model callbacks and associations but have never seen them all really documented anywhere.

Obviously there will be some disagreement and there is probably not one true way but that's to be expected. I'm very curious to hear how other people organize their code. Thanks.

Comment: Might help to give some examples of specific models you want to organize the code for.

Answer (score 2):

I use this simple three-step order:

1) Relationships
2) Validations
3) Methods

I don't think I would ever put anything after the methods or before the relationships.

Comment: I like your approach - seems intuitive. But where do you put mass assignment security code like `attr_accessible` and model callbacks such as `before_create`?

Comment: I put attr_accessible after relations and callbacks just before the other methods.